# Sending object over network or saving into hard disk

Tags: c++

```
class shape {};
class circle: public shape {};
class square: public shape {};
class doc {
    shape* ar[3];
    doc() {
        createShape();
    }
    shape* appendShape();
};

doc d;
```

I need to save this object d into hard disk as binary format or send this data over network so that other program can populate this object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you are looking for object **serialization**. You might want to take a look at the [Boost Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) library. It can be used to save your objects to a file or a binary stream that could be sent over the network. It also can serialize your objects into an XML representation.